# IJCAD Mechanical 2022で「-amlayergroup」コマンドを行った時と同じ結果にしたい

Tags: vb.net, ijcad

現在、AutoCAD Mechanical 2018からIJCAD Mechanical 2022へ
VB.Netで実装したカスタマイズコマンドの移植を行っています。

AutoCAD Mechanical 2018 で以下の処理を行っております。

```
Dim acadApp As GrxCAD.Interop.GcadApplication = GrxCAD.ApplicationServices.Application.AcadApplication
Dim activeDoc As GrxCAD.Interop.GcadDocument = acadApp.ActiveDocument

Dim cmdText As String = "(command ""-amlayergroup"" ""g"" ""t"" ""<BASE>"" """" ""o"" ""MSYM"") "
activeDoc.SendCommand(cmdText)
```

IJCAD Mechanical 2022でも同じ処理を行いたいのですが、
IJCAD Mechanical 2022には「-amlayergroup」コマンドがございません。

また、同じ内容のコマンド「gmlayergroup」では、
コマンド ライン上で操作を行うことができません。

IJCAD Mechanical 2022でも同じ処理を行う方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> IJCAD Mechanical 2022でも同じ処理を行う方法を教えていただけないでしょうか？
>
> ```
> "(command ""-amlayergroup"" ""g"" ""t"" ""<BASE>"" """" ""o"" ""MSYM"") "
> ```

・`""g"" ""t"" ""<BASE>""` 部分について
フリーズ解除自体は、-LAYERコマンドの[フリーズ解除(T)]オプションで行えるので、フリーズ解除したい画層を取得して-LAYERコマンドを使うことで代用ができると思います。

・`""o"" ""MSYM""` 部分について
こちらは-GMLAYERコマンドの[オブジェクトキー(O)]オプションで代用ができると思います。